# Logging in an Angular + WebAPI app?

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular app that uses a WEB API service for data.

I want to log basically everything in a separated table in the database. Things like:

- User x logged in on 2016-03-13
- User x created a new product on xx
- User x updated their profile
  etc.

Basically every action, the user makes, I want to log.
The app is a fairly simple app, where the user has to login to do anything. Once logged in, they can create a couple of different items, edit them and delete some of them again.

So, my question is: how do I make such a log functionality? If I could get info like IP also, with each request, that would be great.

Any ideas?

Also, can it log when there occurs javascript exceptions? Like elmah for ASP.NET?

Comment: Use Log4Net Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/  Configure for WebApi:  http://devthings.com.ua/implementing-logging-for-asp-net-web-api-with-log4net/

Comment: What you are describing is either auditing or logging (there is a difference). Actions being logged to a table have nothing to do with angular, only the server side (web api). Usually this is considered an Aspect (see [Cross cutting concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern)). You could handle it using a web api filter or a static class, it depends on what you want to capture (user info, action, details). As of now this question is too broad to give a specific answer to. Please review those links, give something a try, and get back with a specific question.